# Can I find differences between 2 MongoDB documents?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have the following document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : id,
    "name" : "Tom Cruise",
    "movies" : [
        {
                "movie_id" : id,
                "name" : "Mission Impossible",
                "yr_released": 1996
        },
        {
                "movie_id" : id,
                "name" : "Minority Report",
                "yr_released": 2002
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are my POCO's:

```
public class Actor
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("movies")]
    public List<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movies
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("yr_released")]
    public int YearReleased
}
```

Let's say the next day, the document gets updated but the last movie name gets changed from "Minority Report" to "Vanilla Sky".  I want to find out what changed in the sub documents.  This is the sample code that I used (which doesn't work):

```
var yesterdayQuery = (yesterdayColl.AsQueryable<Actor>()
    .Where (b => b.Name.Contains("Cruise"))).ToList();
var todayQuery = (todayColl.AsQueryable<Actor>()
    .Where (b => b.Name.Contains("Cruise"))).ToList();
var diff = todayQuery.Except(yesterdayQuery);
```

Since Mongodb's C# driver doesn't have Except() support, I thought that if I used Linq to Objects as a workaround, I would be able to find the difference.  I guess I was wrong.  Basically, I would like to find the following differences between the documents:

- If a property value has been changed
- If a document or sub-document has been deleted
- If a sub-document has been added

My question is:  How can I write a strongly-typed query using the C# driver (hopefully) to achieve this?

Comment: If you override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods on your POCOs, the `Except` method should work.

Comment: Side note - you are loading actors from same collection for same condition. `diff` should always be empty

Comment: thx @lazyberezovsky.  I've corrected that but still get the same problem.

Comment: @Gabe, I'm not familiar with overriding methods, so I did some research online.  I found this site:  http://ntrush.blogspot.ca/2012/10/strongly-typed-id-for-mongodb-c-driver.html.  I copied the bit of code from the first class but only for the methods you mentioned.  I don't think that was it, because I'm still getting an error:  'UserQuery.Id<T>' does not implement interface member 'System.IEquatable<UserQuery.Id<T>>.Equals(UserQuery.Id<T>)'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MongoDB, but I think you would write your class like this:

```
public class Actor
{
    // equal objects must have equal hash codes
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    // objects with the same Id are equal
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Actor other = obj as Actor;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("movies")]
    public List<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Now, I get this weird error.  "The type or namespace name 'other' could not be found".  Btw, I'm trying this out from LINQPad v4.47.02.  Not sure if that's relevant here.

Comment: Oh, it should be `Actor other = obj as Actor;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know **what** changed and not just **if** it was changed it isn't really a MogngoDB question.
you need 2 copies of your data. Then you need to go property by property (with reflection if you want it to be more generic) and get the new values.
The old copy can be saved in the DB and the new one only in memory.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Your class needs to have something like `GetChanges(Actor actor)` that compares 2 instances of Actor. And before you update the new value of an Actor in the db, you compare it to the old value and save the changes.